# String Parse , Lexer or Regex

Tags: php, string, parsing, converters, lexer

```
$filter = 'id,name,questions.fields(id,text,options.limit(5).offset(3).fields(id,text),type).limit(10).offset(2),create_date';
```

I want to parse `$filter` like this. (`$filter` value is dynamic.)

```
$fields = array(
    'id',
    'name',
    'questions'=>array(
        'fields'=>array(
            'id',
            'text',
            'options'=>array(
                'fields'=>array(
                        'id',
                        'text'
                    ),
                'limit'=>5,
                'offset'=>3
            ),
            'type'
        ),
        'limit'=>10,
        'offset'=>2
    ),
    'create_date'
);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Shouldn't you have `limit(5),offset(3)` instead of `limit(5).offset(3)` ?

Comment: correct @one-trick-pony, it should be "limit(5).offset(3)"